# How to edit Mercurial .hgignore to permanently ignore all bin and obj folders?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore, sourcetree

I am using BitBucket with SourceTree on my home computer and on my laptop.
When I commit on one computer, the bin and obj folders are ignored.
When I commit on the other computer, changes to files in the bin and obj folders display.

The .hgignore file is under source control so I don't understand why it does not behave the same on both computers.

Both computers run VS2015 Update 1 and SourceTree 1.7.32059

The repositories do have different folder names.

The .hgignore file on my home computer is (trimmed down)

```
syntax: glob
MyAppDocuments
SBD.MyApp.Web\MyAppdocs
*.nupkg
```

Why does this not work the same way on my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Sourcetree supports both the usual .hgignore file in the Mercurial repository and a global .hgignore which is stored in `C:\users\<username>\.hgignore_global`.

It sounds like you've got the bin and obj folders added to the global ignore on one computer, but not on the other.

Really the bin and obj entries should be in the .hgignore in your repository.  If you can locate the global ignore file you might be able to copy the required entries from there into your repository .hgignore file.

[Information taken from this question on Atlassian support.](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/223679/new-file-automatically-ignored)

Comment: The file can be found from inside SourceTree using Tools->Options->Mercurial